# Getting a Syntax Error in python script

Tags: if-statement, syntax, syntax-error, comparison-operators

I keep getting a syntax error on what seems to be no error. It is caused within a if statement with an and comparison and im not sure why. this is also my first semester using python so please help.

```
while userWins < 2 or CPUWins < 2:
    answer = random.randrange(3)
    print(str(answer))
    print("[1]-- Rock")
    print("[2]-- Paper")
    print("[3}-- Scissors")
    guess = int(input("Enter a number corresponding to a choice.")
    if guess == 1 and answer == 3:  #<--This is the line that keeps getting the syntax error
        userWins = userWins + 1
        print(name, " wins that round")
        RoundScore(userWins, CPUWins, name)
    elif guess == 1 and answer = 2:
        CPUWins += 1
        print(name, " loses that round")
        RoundScore(userWins, CPUWins, name)
```

This is the Error that IDLE gives me

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Cosc-151/Assignment5/a5_v34.py", line 1, in 
    import Mods
  File "E:/Cosc-151/Assignment5\Mods.py", line 61
    if guess == 1 and answer == 3:
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

thanks

Comment: A lot of times when you get a syntax error, the actual error is on the previous line.  In this case I guess your missing a ')'

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a close-paren on the previous line (to close the `int` call).

On the line before you need to have

```
guess = int(input("Enter a number corresponding to a choice."))
                                                              ^
                                                       You forgot this
```